# Elasticsearch 5.0+ not working magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch in my local server successfully.I am not able to reindex the catalog search indexer.Please check attached screenshots.

[image]

When i click on the test connection then it shows me successful connection.Please check the configuration and let me know why it does not working?

[image]

Do i need to any third party extension to use elasticsearch like smile elastic search or else etc...?

**I am using Magento 2.3 version.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The _all meta field is now disabled by default

On new mappings, the _all meta field that contains a copy of the text from each field is now disabled by default. The query_string and simple_query_string queries that previously used _all to search will now check if _all is enabled/disabled and switch to executing the query across all fields if _all is disabled. _all can no longer be configured for indices created with Elasticsearch version 6.0 or later.

> Multiple mapping types are not supported in indices created in 6.0
>
> The ability to have multiple mapping types per index has been removed
>   in 6.0. New indices will be restricted to a single type. This is the
>   first step in the plan to remove mapping types altogether. Indices
>   created in 5.x will continue to support multiple mapping types.

ElasticSearch docs regarding changes to the _all meta field in v6 for reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-6.0.html#_the_literal__all_literal_meta_field_is_now_disabled_by_default

**Note:** 
Magento Commerce version 2.3.x supports the following Elasticsearch versions:

- Elasticsearch 5.2.x
- Elasticsearch 2.x
- Magento 2.3 uses Elasticsearch PHP client version 5.2. (Before
  version 2.3, Magento used PHP client version 5.1.)

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Okay let me try to install 5.2.x version instead of 6.6.1 version.

Comment: @SunnyRahevar any update about issue have you resolve the issue by installing  5.2.x version?

Comment: I have installed 5.2.x but somehow elasticsearch not started.I have ran all commands for start elasticsearch and when i run this curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200' command is shows me connection refused.i have changed host in the elasticsearch.yml file too. But don't know how to fix an error.

Comment: Please check the elasticsearch install and configure documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html you may miss something. I am sure, if you successfully install elasticsearch 5.2.x it will resolve your question issue, if my answer helps please mark my answer correct and upvote my answer. thanks

Comment: Sure.Once it will be done i will mark your answer as correct.Don't worry. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I have installed 5.x successfully and reindexing working fine for me.Thanks!

Comment: No Problem Brother. Voted to your question as well. +1

Comment: @MuhammadHasham can you please tell me how to add elasticsearch 7.x version in Magento 2.3.3?